# Is there a strategy I could use to beat Day 30 of the Minesweeper Advent Calendar?

Tags: minesweeper

<sub>Note: this is not in conjunction with my [Minesweeper puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A86115+is%3Aq+%22filling+in+an+8x8+minesweeper+grid+with+mines%22)</sub>

---

So I was playing Day 30 on the [Minesweeper Advent Calendar](https://heptaveegesimal.com/2018/advent-calendar/bonus-days.php) on heptaveegesimal.com when I noticed something weird:

Take a look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THWt6.png) screenshot:

[image]

There are only numbers going up to 3, and the numbers appear to be in different colors.

Now, let's talk about the different color mines that can appear on this day (this I found out after a little bit of testing, the instructions are worded sort of weirdly):

| Red | Brown | Green | Blue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 mines on the diagonal tiles, # amount of mines on the orthogonal tiles | # amount of mines on the orthogonal tiles, all diagonal tiles are safe | # amount of mines on the orthogonal and 2 diagonal tiles | Unsure what this means, however I think it means that there are # amount of mines on the orthogonal tiles and one diagonal mine. |

Which I actually used that information to get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4cQo.png) far and then purposely failed to see that all but one of my flags was correct (the red circles show where I placed flags if they were correct):

[image]

Now obviously, I'm not good at this type of Minesweeper, however it does seem that there is some sort of strategy to win this day. However, I doubt that I'm very aware of it (unless I've already described it). So my question is:

Is there a strategy that I could use to beat this puzzle, or have I already described the strategy in enough detail where I should already be able to beat Day 30?

---

<sub>Update before I post: just got 57/280 tiles with 19/120 correct flags with only one incorrectly placed in 3:04.972</sub>

Comment: holy crap I think I might have already described the strategy (I just got 133/280 tiles and 58/120 flags (2 incorrectly placed) in 11:46.723) but it might just be beginner's luck tbh.

Comment: Okay no I have definitely figured out the strategy (141/280 tiles in 1:06.641)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at it and playing a round, it looks like you've nearly understood it.

The number in the square always corresponds to the number of mines in orthogonal tiles.
The color of the square always corresponds to the number of mines in diagonal tiles, according to the following:

| Color | Number of mines |
| --- | --- |
| Brown | 0 |
| Blue | 1 |
| Green | 2 |
| Red | 3 |
| Purple-ish color | 4 |

In this way, each tile actually encodes **more** information than a normal minesweeper tile would -- instead of only knowing the total number of connecting mines, you know how many touch diagonally and how many touch orthogonally. As long as you can keep track of which color means what, normal minesweeper strategies should apply.

As noted in the description, because it gives you so much information, the puzzle-maker has coded for 120 mines to be placed in the puzzle, making it very hazardous.

Finally, another gimmick I noticed as I played is that the grid **wraps on the X and Y axises**, meaning that cell 1-10 is next to cell 20-10.

Comment: I'm aware of the wrapping (that's because it's a torus) also your table is broken

Comment: Took me four tries to fix the table syntax (I needed to add two newlines between it and the paragraph before) but I finally got it aha... Also, cool site! I've now been doing minesweeper variants for the past hour